# switching from one vpn into another does not work in ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I use OpenVPN 2.4.7 and Ubuntu 20.04.
After importing first.ovpn the vpn to first works.
After importing second.ovpn the vpn to second works.
When i switch from first vpn to second vpn i ran into a timeout.

```
VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed(1)
VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

Have anyone an idea how i can solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I have two vpn configurations imported. When I disconnect from one and connect to the other i ran into a timeout. So I have to delete this configuration and make a fresh import from the .ovpn file - then I'm able to connect.